# find a keyword while tailing a log and then do X

Tags: linux, perl, logging, tail

Can i have a script running in a Linux environment that tails a log file and then as soon as it sees a certain keyword ( say "EndAPP") it runs another script? If so how ?

Comment: yes, it's easy. You can use bash or perl. Another tip: inotify may also be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/~mgrabnar/File-Tail-0.99.3/Tail.pm)

```
use File::Tail;

my $file=File::Tail->new("/some/log/file");
while (defined(my $line = $file->read)) {
    system("/path/to/second/script") if($line =~ /EndApp/) ;
}
```

Comment: thank you for both answers and the comment, but this is what i ended up using.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code...

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_TO_TAIL=/file/to/tail
PATTERN="EndAPP"
APP_TO_EXEC="app.bin"


tail -1f ${FILE_TO_TAIL} |
while read -r line
do
    if [ ${PATTERN}=${line} ]; then
        ./${APP_TO_EXEC}
    fi
done
exit
```